# Using ffmpeg to create looping apng

Tags: ffmpeg, apng

I'm trying to create looping apng files from mkvs. My problem is that they don't loop. The files play once, but stop.

This is what I'm doing:

```
 ffmpeg -ss 16:43 -i ./10.mkv -loop 10 -t 1 -filter:v "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, crop=1200:800, hqdn3d=1.5:1.5:6:6, scale=600:400"  10-file-2.apng
```

I've tried -loop -1 -loop 10 -loop 1 but there is no looping done. My version is

> ffmpeg-3.3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz

Comment: `ffmpeg -i 'input.mp4' -framerate 5 -plays 0 screenshot.webp` was a helpful command for me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The parameter for looping APNGs is `-plays`.

```
ffmpeg -ss 16:43 -i ./10.mkv -plays 10 -t 1 -vf "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, crop=1200:800, hqdn3d=1.5:1.5:6:6, scale=600:400"  10-file-2.apng
```

- `-plays 0`: loops forever
- `-plays 1`: plays once (i.e. no loop)
- etc.

Comment: Do you have a documentation link? And how do I set infinite loops? -1 `Value -1.000000 for parameter 'plays' out of range [0 - 4.29497e+09]`

Comment: No doc for apng muxer at all! Strange. Anyway, `0` for infinite loops.

Comment: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/c463b81d037fd88fdda432324b995d82510a5bc7/libavformat/apngenc.c#L278

Comment: What does this part do hqdn3d=1.5:1.5:6:6 ?

Comment: That's a denoiser. See docs at http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hqdn3d-1

Comment: I just get "option plays not found". :-(  EDIT: actually, you have to put `-plays 0` after the `-i file` option for some reason and then it works.

Comment: @Jez  The plays option belongs to the APNG muxer so it goes along with the output options. Have a read of http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Description

Comment: Yeah I had to put it after the `-i` argument and then it worked.