# FFMPEG control delay and looping for generating APNG

Tags: animation, ffmpeg, imagemagick, apng

I have a (random selection) of JPG images that I want to use to make into an APNG animation using ffmpeg (to test the process). They are all the same dimensions (256x256). But I cannot seem to get the correct syntax to control the frame delay and loop control (to loop forever). Is it possible to set these parameters using ffmpeg when creating an APNG from a sequence of images? If so, can someone provide the proper syntax and/or show an example command? I have searched the ffmpeg documentation and cannot seem to find relevant syntax.

I can do the following, but it will not accept -delay nor -loop. I use Imagemagick to pipe in the images.

This works, but does not loop, and runs very fast.

```
magick lena.jpg mandril3.jpg monet2.jpg zelda1.jpg PNG:- | ffmpeg -i - x.apng
```

This gives errors about delay and/or loop:

```
magick lena.jpg mandril3.jpg monet2.jpg zelda1.jpg PNG:- | ffmpeg -i - -delay 1000 -loop -1 x.apng
```

I am also curious to know if it is possible to specify a sequence of images directly in ffmpeg as input without using ImageMagick.

Sorry, I am a relative novice with ffmpeg.  I am using ffmpeg 4.2.1.

Comment: Fred, part of the answer is here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/43797017/2836621

Comment: You can probably set the delay like this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video but I'm not near anything I can test on.

Comment: Thanks `Mark`. The -plays works to control the looping. But the second link does not provide a valid method for doing the delay using `setpts`.

Comment: If you wish to loop, you can't pipe the images*. Use the demuxer method at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer.  *technically, you can but it's memory consuming.

Comment: `@Gyan`  Thanks, but that is not what I want. But your link does tell me what to do for the delay -- use the input framerate. That works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Looping

You can set looping with the `-plays` output option. `0` is infinite, `1` is no loop, `2` will play twice, etc.

`-plays` is an option specific (aka a [private option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#AVOptions)) for the APNG muxer. You can see private options for a specific muxer with `ffmpeg -h muxer=apng`. See [What are all codecs and formats supported by FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20587693/) for more examples.

Another private option for APNG is `-final_delay` to force delay after the last frame. Accepts a value in seconds.

## Providing images to ffmpeg

### Image demuxer

The most common method is to use the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1).

It accepts a numbered sequence such as `image_001.png`, `image_002.png`, etc:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 3 -i image_%03d.png -plays 0 output.apng
```

Or a glob (at least on Linux & macOS):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" output.apng
```

Set delay/timing with the `-framerate` input option as shown in the examples above. This is a private option of the image demuxer.

### Pipe

You can pipe the images to `ffmpeg` like you do in your question. Can be useful in combination with other tools to provide the order you prefer.

For example, using `sort` is helpful your image series uses natural/version numbering such as `1.png`, `2.png`, ..., `10.png`, etc. Otherwise `ffmpeg` would order them as `1.png`, `10.png`, `2.png`.

```
cat $(find . -name '*.png' -print | sort -V) | ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i - -plays 1 output.apng
```

### Concat demuxer

Or use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) if you want to provide a list of files. Each image can have its own duration.

1. Create `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file 'lena.jpg'
   duration 1
   file 'mandril3.jpg'
   duration 0.5
   file 'monet2.jpg'
   duration 3
   file 'zelda1.jpg'
   duration 2
   ```

   Duration value is in seconds.
2. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -plays 0 output.apng
   ```

If you omit `duration`, and want an even delay/timing between images you can use the `-r` input option. This example will play at 1 frame per second.

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -f concat -i input.txt -plays 0 output.apng
```

Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer).

Comment: `@llogan`Thanks. The -framerate is what I wanted. I found that out myself as well, just before you posted. With regard to input file specification, how can I provide a list of images without using wild cards or piping, especially if the names and suffixes are different. Will ffmpeg permit a list of files in some way?

Comment: @fmw42 Another option is the concat demuxer as mentioned by Gyan. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I think I have what I need using -framerate and -plays.

Comment: A good page for information about using image input is at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow